# How restrict Sequel ruby to allow SELECT statement only fetch method?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am letting my users execute sql queries in the app I am building. They can input database connection strings (mysq, pg, and other rdbms supported)
Is there a way to allow SELECT statements only on fetch methos like this

```
   client = Sequel.connect "mysql2://user:pass@hostname/some_db"
   client.fetch("SELECT * FROM sample_table").all
```

and disallow the following

```
   client.fetch("DROP DATABASE some_db").all
   client.fetch("TRUNCATE some_table").all
   client.fetch("ALTER some_table").all
```

and can I also get the tables and datatypes of each tables columns using sequel gem?

Comment: What about parsing the query and determine whether it's a select query or something else? And yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a dangerous thing. It is hard to properly sanitize input against all cases.
Just think of procedures, dynamically craftet SQL, concatenated statements, PLSQL, up/downcase, SQL Variants, errors in your sanitizer, ...

And you should never underestimate the creativity of malicious users.

Best would be to handle this on the DB level and create read only user with the proper access rights.